# Today I visited Stack Overflow and my profile picture has vanished - but I didn't change it

Tags: support, status-deferred, profile-picture, facebook

I noticed today that I no longer have a profile picture. It simply displays like this, which I assume is the default:

[image: no profile picture]

I haven't updated my profile in ages and I have had the same profile picture for as long as I can remember, which is why its disappearance was very noticeable to me.

Has anyone else experienced the same? What is the cause for its disappearance?

I just viewed source on the picture and it directs to a Facebook URL: `https://graph.facebook.com/{MY FB USER ID HERE}/picture?type=large`

Comment: Related: [Default profile picture from Facebook is being displayed, instead of Facebook picture if a user joined before Stack using Facebook API v2+](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355805/289905).

Comment: more like face-less book

Comment: Indeed it's failing to fulfil it's one main selling point by the looks of things.

Comment: Facebook encountered Stack Overflow. No more room for faces in stack. Reverting to default face.

Comment: And.. [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAvct.png) is what it looks like for everyone that blocks social networks :)

Comment: That's certainly not the "default" picture, not for Stack Overflow. Blame Facebook.

Comment: Looks like Facebook changed the requirements for accessing profile images. I don't have much else to offer right now, we'll need to investigate further.

Comment: [Jon responded to the MSE report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361184), so just to echo it here: this is on our backlog, but there's no ETA at the moment.

Comment: I've had the same issue. I entered Facebook and saw that StackOverflow permission on FB had expired. I renewed it, tried logging out and logging in here, but didn't work